# Как правильно работать с сессиями в node+express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сессия, express, express-sessions

Всем доброго!
Решил попробовать поигратся немного с авторизацией, с помощю сессий.
Столкнулся с проблемой когда заканчивается срок жизни сессии **cookie: {maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 1))}** повторно засетить что то в **req.session** не получается :(

Вот кусок моего кода:

```
let session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'aaa2C44-4D44-WppQ38Siuyiuy',
    cookie: {maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 1))},
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

let checkSignIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user) {   // после истичения сессии req.session.user всегда undefined, 
                                       //несмотря на то что в 
                                       //логине я повторно задаю это
                                     // свойство req.session.user = user['_id']
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}

app.post("/login",  (req, res) => {
   if(req.body.usr == user && req.body.pwd == password)
           req.session.user = user['_id']
           res.redirect("/manage");
        } else {
            console.log('Could not find user')
            res.render('login')
        }


    })


})


app.get("/manage", checkSignIn, (req, res) => {
        res.render('index')
})
```

В результате первый раз логин проходит удачно, но после того как сесия истечет, повторно залогинится не удается, почему то при проверке в кастомном миделвере **checkSignIn req.session.user == undefined** хотя в **"/login"** это свойство задается так же как и в первый раз **req.session.user = user['_id']**

Не понимаю почему так происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить

Answer (score 2):

Решил! Заменил  **cookie.maxAge** с дати на время и все отлично :)
тоесть с  **new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000 * 1))**   на  **90000**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после `req.session.user = user['_id']`
вызвать [req.session.save()](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsavecallback)

Comment: Такой вариант у меня тоже не проходил :(